# Objective-C: Find consonants in string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a string that contains words with consonants and vowels. How can I extract only consonants from the string?

```
NSString *str = @"consonants.";
```

Result must be:

```
cnsnnts
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make a character set with all the vowels (@"aeiouy")

```
+ (id)characterSetWithCharactersInString:(NSString *)aString
```

then use the

```
- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set
```

method.

EDIT: This will only remove vowels at the beginning and end of the string as pointed out in the other post, what you could do instead is use

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator
```

then stick the components back together. You may also need to include capitalized versions of the vowels in the set, and if you want to also deal with accents (à á è è ê ì etc...) you'll probably have to include that also.

Comment: Thk for the reply, i tried with this:    NSCharacterSet *vowelsSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"AEIOU"];
    NSString *consonants = [[NSString alloc]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:vowelsSet];

Comment: Note that Mario's example also removes punctuation. Your solution should extract the consonants, rather than just removing the vowels.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` wont work as it only trim leading and ending characters, but you could try using a regular expression and substitution like this:

```
[[NSRegularExpression
  regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^bcdefghjklmnpqrstvwx]"
  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
  error:NULL]
 stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str
 options:0
 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])
 withTemplate:@""]
```

You probably want to tune the regex and options for your needs.

Comment: Hmm that's what `invertedSet` is suppose to fix. But I now see that it wont work as `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only trim leading and ending characters.

Comment: I guess i would have been named strip instead of trim if it should work as we first thought, tricky :) Updated my answer to use a regular expression and substitution instead.

Comment: good edit, may have to deal with localized versions of consonants (like ç), if needed. It would be very useful for Apple to have [NSCharacterSet setWithAllConsonants] or something similar...

Comment: Also possibly problematic if characters like . # ( ) < > and so on need to be kept.

Comment: Yeah Mario should probably tune the regex for his need, like change it to `@"[aeiou]"`

Comment: Mattias thak for reply. <br /> i write this code:<br />  NSString *str= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", surnameField.text]; <br /> How can add your code?

Comment: Hmm not sure but if you want to "strip" surname you should probably do something like this: `NSString *str = /* insert my code here but replace "str" with "surnameField.text" */`

Answer (score 0):

Possible, for sure not-optimal, solution. I'm printing intermediate results for your learning. Take care of memory allocation (I didn't care). Hopefully someone will send you a better solution, but you can copy and paste this for the moment.

```
NSString *test = @"Try to get all consonants";
NSMutableString *found = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSInteger loc = 0;
NSCharacterSet *consonants = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"];
while(loc!=NSNotFound && loc<[test length]) {
    NSRange r = [[test lowercaseString] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:consonants options:0 range:NSMakeRange(loc, [test length]-loc)];
    if(r.location!=NSNotFound) {
        NSString *temp = [test substringWithRange:r];
        NSLog(@"Range: %@ Temp: %@",NSStringFromRange(r), temp);
        [found appendString:temp];
        loc=r.location+r.length;
    } else {
        loc=NSNotFound;
    }
}

NSLog(@"Found: %@",found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `NSString` category that does the job:

```
- (NSString *)consonants
{
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithString:self];
    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"aeiou"];

    while(1)
    {
        NSRange range = [result rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(range.location == NSNotFound)
            break;

        result = [result stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    }


    return result;
}
```