# Objective-c extract only vowels in a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C: Find consonants in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859683/objective-c-find-consonants-in-string)

I have a string that contains words with consonants and vowels. How put only vowels into a new string?
I have write this code but not work.

`NSString *str = @"consonants";

NSCharacterSet *consonantSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwx"];

NSString *vowels = [[NSString alloc]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:consonantSet];`

Result of vowels string must be: "ooa".

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please add the homework tag.

Comment: You have asked virtually the exact same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859683/objective-c-find-consonants-in-string - please don't post near identical versions of the same question repeatedly.

Comment: @lxt, thanks for pointing this. After seeing your comment I have deleted my answer and cast a close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't try your code but it seems like this line of code is wrong in your case:

```
NSString *vowels = [[NSString alloc] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:consonantSet];
```

You should be using:

```
NSString *vowels = [str  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:consonantSet];
```

Comment: That's still not quite right - youre only removing characters from the start and end of the string ;) However, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859683/objective-c-find-consonants-in-string so don't answer it - it's going to get closed soon ;)